# asymptote error after upgrading to ghostscript 9.54

Tags: asymptote, ghostscript

After system upgrade to ghostscript version 9.54 I get an error when compiling assymptote. The error seems to occur when the `animate` module is imported and and then the `label` function is used.

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
import animate;
label("$x$");
```

The error message is:

```
 _shipout(prefix,f,currentpatterns,format,wait,view,t);
         ^
 /home/hafid/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 104.11: runtime: 
 Command  exited abnormally: gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -P -dSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY 
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEPSCrop -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dMaxSubsetPct=100 
-dEncodeColorImages=true -dEncodeGrayImages=true -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 
-dAutoRotatePages=/None -g612x792 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=72.525 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=106.516 
-sOutputFile=Calcul_reactions.pdf -c .setsafe -f Calcul_reactions_.eps 

 Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Tue May  4 11:01:50
```

Comment: It is a bug in 9.54, that has already been reported and fixed (in the Git version), but not released yet. If you are interested:  https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=703783 . You will need to downgrade to 9.53.3 for now. Or get the Git version and compile it on your own.

Comment: @AlexG thank you for the information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a known bug in Ghostscript 9.54.0 that has already been fixed, but not released yet. For now, you may downgrade GS, or avoid internal use of Ghostscript by running `asy` like so:

```
asy -tex pdflatex example.asy
```

---

The GS version that comes with TeXLive-21 for the win32 platform has the patch already incorporated. So there, the error does not occur.